# Использование регулярного выражения в php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть массив в php, надо вытащить все, что находиться между ()

Пытался так, но что-то не помогло
Пример массива

```
<script type="text/javascript">var obbx_117848907_44771=new JCCatalogElement(какие-то символы которые надо вытащить);</script>
```

Вот такую регулярку пробовал

```
preg_match_all('/script\((.*)\)\;/script', $catsHTML, $new_price_block);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$catsHTML = '<script type="text/javascript">var obbx_117848907_44771=new JCCatalogElement(какие-то символы которые надо вытащить);</script>';
preg_match_all('/<script.+\((.*)\)/', $catsHTML, $new_price_block);
print_r($new_price_block[1]);
```